# Check if build will be successful with excluded pending changes

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs, version-control

I'm currently working on a solution using TFS as source control and no continuous integration setup with little hope of setting one up in the near future.

I've made changes to several files and would like to check in those changes but want to split it in different check-ins so they can each have meaningful commit messages so in order to do that I'm excluding files from each check-in. The solution with all the changes builds but I would like the solution to be able to build in each of those changesets.

I know I can just shelve the changes I don't want to commit and undo the changes and unshelve them after each commit, and that's what I've been doing so far, but I thought there might be an easier way.

Is there a configuration that would allow me to check if a solution will build with the excluded changes in TFS?

Answer (score 0):

No，you can't build with the excluded changes. Using shelvest is the only way for your situation.

Otherwise, you need to manually specify the files you want to check in for each commit. You can specify which file changes you want to check in by dragging them between the Included Changes and Excluded Changes sections of the Pending Changes page. You can also scope your check-in as you work in other areas of Visual Studio:

In **Solution Explorer**, select one of the following:

- The solution
- One or more of the code projects
- One or more files

After you select the items, open their context menu, and choose Check In.

In **Source Control Explorer**, select one or more items with pending changes or one or more folders that contain items with pending changes. (Items with pending changes are indicated by this symbol: TFSC Checked-Out Status Icon). Open the context menu for the selected items, and choose Check In.

Comment: Patrick, can't he Shelve both sets of changes and build the Shelveset (private/buddy build)?

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario, CI build is the better solution, I recommend that you to set up a CI build.

On the other hand, you may consider Git, for this way, you can create many local branches.